# Prevent gmail from showing inline images as attachments

Tags: java, spring, email, gmail

I am using the [spring samples](http://websystique.com/spring/spring-4-email-with-attachment-tutorial/) to send inline images. It works but gmail shows images also as attachments. How to avoid it?

[image]

The code is pretty simple.

```
public class Email {

    public static  MimeMessagePreparator getContentAsInlineResourceMessagePreparator(final String to) {

        MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {

            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");

                helper.setSubject("Email with inline image");
                helper.setFrom("fake@yourshop.com");
                helper.setTo(to);

                String content = "Dear pedrofb...";
                helper.setText("<html><body><p>" + content + "</p><img src='cid:company-logo'></body></html>", true);
                helper.addInline("company-logo", new ClassPathResource("logo.png"));
            }
        };
        return preparator;
    }
    public final static void main (String argv[]){
        //Basic SMTP configuration
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost(host);
        mailSender.setPort(port);

        MimeMessagePreparator preparator = getContentAsInlineResourceMessagePreparator("myemail@gmail.com");            
        mailSender.send(preparator);
    }

}
```

My question is similar to [How to stop embedded images in email being displayed as attachments by GMail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040358/how-to-stop-embedded-images-in-email-being-displayed-as-attachments-by-gmail) but the answer is very old and it does not show how to configure spring properly. I do not want to build the message parts&headers myself

---

Posted the raw message in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/uiQMJUHQ)

Comment: The second parameter of `MimeMessageHelper` also takes code, https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html. Please play around with all 4 modes and see if any of them help you with the gmail email. Also I would suggest to try with `companyLogo` instead of `company-logo`

Comment: @TarunLalwani thanks. No luck...

Comment: Please do a raw view of the email in gmail and create a pastebin of the same and share

Comment: @TarunLalwani, posted raw message https://pastebin.com/uiQMJUHQ

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is with `MimeType` determination

[image: MimeType]

The `png` extension is treated as `image/x-png` instead of `image/png` this causes the issue with Gmail. This has been fixed/changed in `5.X` and may also be in some `4.X` later version also (I am not sure on those). But the fix is quite easy. Change

```
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
```

to

```
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8") {

    @Override
    public void addInline(String contentId, Resource resource) throws MessagingException {
        Assert.notNull(resource, "Resource must not be null");
        String contentType = this.getFileTypeMap().getContentType(resource.getFilename());
        contentType = contentType.replace("x-png", "png");
        this.addInline(contentId, resource, contentType);

    }
};
```

And it will override the `MimeType` to `image/png`

[image: Inline image]

Answer (score 0):

I have executed your code. It works perfectly: I open the resulting email in gmail, I see the inline image, and I don't see any attachment!
This may be due to the library version? I have used the 5.0.5.RELEASE.

If this is not the solution, I guess you may have some uncommon property in your SmtpServer.toJavaMailSender() or in your Gmail settings.

Comment: I am using spring 4.1.9 and javamail 1.4.7. I am using a very simple SMTP configuration